# Design a PCB with an elevated surface in the middle (KiCad)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have designed a PCB where a device is glued and there will be wires bonded from the device to transmission lines on the PCB.

I would like to have the bond pads on the PCB and device on an elevated surface with respect to the rest of the PCB (image attached). I wasn’t able to find a way to render something similar to what I drew in the image. Is this something I can do in KiCad? (as it stands, the PCB is perfectly flat (right bottom image) but I would like to introduce[image] an elevated surface, similar to what I have drawn on the right top.)

Thank you!

Comment: This may be an X-Y problem. What do you want to achieve with the elevation?

Comment: Physically how do expect to do this? The way I can think of, you'd need to add a shim or carrier between the board and the chip. If that's what you have in mind, could you just add the shim to the 3D model of the part, rather than to the board?

Comment: Your picture looks like 2 PCBs to me. That's probably what you'll need to do. How else were you planning to fabricate this?

Comment: Header pins? If you want the 3D model to reflect this, you'll have to read up on how to add custom 3D models to KiCAD. Not easy, not impossible either, but will take some time and fiddling.